# How to apply a custom validation to association in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Item` model and `Theme` model like so:

```
class Item
  belongs_to :mobile_theme, class_name: 'Theme'
end

class Theme
  has_many :items

  enum theme_type: { desktop: 0, mobile: 1 }
end
```

I want to validate that `item.mobile_theme.theme_type == :mobile` when an association is created. ( I want to prevent `Theme` with `theme_type = :desktop` to get associated with `Item` as a `mobile_theme`)

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom validators or custom validation methods https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

```
class Item
  validate :reject_non_mobile_theme

  private

  def reject_non_mobile_theme
    errors.add(:mobile_theme, 'Theme must be mobile') unless mobile_theme.mobile?
  end
```